# Probability of 3 dice with rethrown

Tags: probability, self-study, dice

In a game, three ordinary dice are thrown. If the first throw results in just two dice showing the same number, the die with different number if thrown again. If all numbers are different in the first throw, all are thrown again.

Throw Once:

```
0 same      |        2 same          |        3 same

Throw 3     |  throw 1 (different)   |         stop

Stop        |          Stop          |          N/A
```

Find the probability that all numbers are the same at the points labelled stop?

Comment: Three dice are thrown together, if two are the same number and one is different this one is thrown again? Are you asking what is the probability of getting all three dice with the same number in the first throw, or what is the probability of getting all three dice with same number on the first throw OR on the second throw, if we throw one dice again?

Comment: The game allow rethrow one more time, providing a condition that : 1). 2 are the same, rethrow die with different 2). 3 are different, rethrow all die. At the end of the game, what's the probability that all 3 dice are the same

Comment: Case 1 : 2 number are the same in 1 throw + same color in second throw 3 * (1*1/6*5/6) * 1/6 = 5/72 Case 2: all number are difference in 1 throw + all number are different in 2nd throw (1*5/6*1/6) * (1/6*1/6*1/6*6) Ans : Case 1 + Case 2 but it is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases you need to consider:

1. All three dice are the same in the first throw, let's call the event $e_1$. There are $6^3$ possible outcomes, out of which $6$ are all the same numbers, so $P(e_1) = 6/6^3  =1/36$.
2. All dice are different in the first throw (event $e_2$) AND all three are the same in the second throw (event $e_3$).

   $P(e_2) = (6\cdot 5\cdot 4)/6^3 = 20/36$

   $P(e_3) = P(e_1) = 1/36$

   $P(e_2 \cap e_3) = P(e_2)P(e_3) = 20/36 \cdot 1/36 = 20/6^4$, since the first and the second throw are independent.
3. Two of the dice are the same in the first throw (but not all)($e_4$), and the re-thrown dice will also be the same ($e_5$).

   $P(e_4)=(6\cdot 1 \cdot 5) / 6^3 = 5/36$

   $P(e_5) = 1/6$

   $P(e_4 \cap e_5) = P(e_4)P(e_5) = 5/36 \cdot 1/6 = 5/6^3$

In the end you are interested in $P\big(e_1 \cup(e_2\cap e_3) \cup (e_4 \cap e_5)\big)$, which is $$1/6^2 + 20 / 6^4 + 5/6^3 = 86/6^4 = 6.78\%.$$